# Cannot receive FCM (Push Notification iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I make app by **React Native**.
Few days ago,I was able to receive **FCM**. But now I cannot.

Client app permissions notification, I set Xcode(capability),firebase and Apple Developer(APNs setting).

And console.log tells me success.

But I cannot receive notification. Although few days ago I could.

Is this error in firebase??

I don't know cause, please help me m(_ _)m

=======environment==========

Xcode Version **11.3**
"react-native-firebase": "**^5.6.0**"
"react-native": "**0.61.5**"
"firebase-admin": "**^8.9.0**"

=======addition========

Regenerating APNs and setting, I could receive notification.
But next day, I couldn't receive notification.

APNs is valid in only one day???

Comment: Are you testing on simulator or on real device?

Comment: real device.  On simulator, I cannot??

Comment: Yes on simulator, remote notifications are not supported.

Comment: Thank you. But I tested on real device

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, in your Firebase console number of potential users are eligible for this campaign is 0 currently.

"Estimate based on approximately 0 users who are registered to receive notifications. Some targeted users will not see the message due to device inactivity. For recurring campaigns, estimate is for initial send only."

[image]

Possible solution:

1) If that's the case (0 users are registered)

--> Check if the fcmToken is received.

```
getFcmToken = async () => {
 const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
 if (fcmToken) {
  console.log(fcmToken);
  this.showAlert(‘Your Firebase Token is:’, fcmToken);
 } else {
  this.showAlert(‘Failed’, ‘No token received’);
 }
}
```

2) If the number is not zero

--> Most probably your app is opened in foreground and the notification is not displayed.

--> Try to lock your iPhone screen and the notification will appear, else try to handle it which the app is in foreground

```
messageListener = async () => {
 this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
   const { title, body } = notification;
   this.showAlert(title, body);
 });

 this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
   const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
   this.showAlert(title, body);
 });

 const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
 if (notificationOpen) {
   const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
   this.showAlert(title, body);
 }

 this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
 });
}
```

3) Check if the cert has expired (unlikely) since you mentioned that it's still working a few days back.

Comment: In order to receive in foreground, do I have to write this code???